# What does "4m[terminated]" mean after restarting CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

After installing `CentOS 7` and restart it, it always promptd "`4m[terminated]`". After googling, I can't find the meaning of this phrase. What does this prompt mean? Will it affect normal OS functions?

Comment: You mean it shows up in a shell prompt?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: No, when fininishing installation, and click `reboot` button, it will prompts "4m[terminated]". Then restarted and run OK, But I can't figure out what is the meaning of this word

Comment: I don't have a centos 7 image to try this at the moment, so I'll leave a comment for now. Terminated is printed by a shell when one of the processes created by it have been killed with the TERM signal, and the `4m[` may be an attempt by a shell script (that thinks it is running on a console window) to colorize that word. Clicking on the restart button will, sooner or later, run the `shutdown` or  `reboot` command, which sends a TERM signal to each running process. It shouldn't be anything to be concerned about.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sigterm kill initiated by a CentOS 7 reboot command after a fresh install. It is obviously a issue that needs to be patched as the image is supposed to reboot not halt. Probably has something to do with the reboot or shutdown command that is not interpreted correctly. Basically the machine halts in stead of shutting down and rebooting, something similar to 'reboot -h 0'. Seems to be related to CentOS 7 only from what I can tell.
For now best to just ignore methinks.
To answer your question: no a sigterm 'information only' aka 'FYI' error at shutdown/reboot will not harm your OS or data in any way.